# How do I get the price listed ONLY on the Amazon product page with the API?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I'm using the Amazon API with PHP to return product information. All is well enough except that what I want is the price that you see on the Amazon front page which is sometimes in [Offers][Offer][OfferListing][Price][Amount] and sometimes in [OfferSummary][LowestNewPrice][Amount].

Is there no way to always get the same price that Amazon shows people? I tried always choosing the lower price, but that ended up picking the lowest new offer from Marketplace sellers that, when you factor in shipping was more than what Amazon was charging.

There's an Amazon API test function here: http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/scratchpad/index.html (though you won't be able to play with it if you don't have your own Amazon API setup).

Answer (score 2):

The operation you need to call is

```
GetCompetitivePricingForASIN
```

or

```
GetCompetitivePricingForSKU
```

The price showed to the costumer (and including shipping) is located here:

```
         ....
         <Price>
            <LandedPrice>  
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>34.27</Amount> //<<<<<< this one!
            </LandedPrice>
         ....
```

Comment: This goes to a page for Amazon europe and I can't find it on the Amazon API page. There's a testbed here and it's not listed as an option: http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/scratchpad/index.html

Comment: Have a look on http://developer.amazonservices.com , there You'll find the API documentation at documentation/ product api

Comment: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/index.html << here is the entire link to the documentation, and here the mws scratchpad https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html

Comment: Right. Of course I checked the documentation, but there's some other factor involved that I can't figure out. Sometimes the price listed on the front is listed under one area ad sometimes the other. That is the missing information that I'm looking for.

Comment: No, the price is definitely always the landed price, I'm very sure as I do this for quite a number of customers

Comment: Right. So where is the "landedprice" in the response set that's available to me through the API? MWS is for SELLERS which I am not (unless there's something I'm misreading in the docs). I'm using Amazon Web Services API.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't know this, might have been good to mention in your question, though. Well, get a seller account then, you can use this as a developer account only..